# Merge two dynamic lists and override values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have two dynamic lists, with each list item including three properties: 'Id' (int), 'LikesRed' (bool) and 'LikesBlue' (bool).

I would like to merge both lists, grouping each item by it's 'Id', but I would also like to override any 'false' values with any 'true' values.

So for example, here is the data for my two lists:

```
List1

{ Id = 1, LikesRed = True, LikesBlue = False }
{ Id = 2, LikesRed = True, LikesBlue = False }
{ Id = 4, LikesRed = False, LikesBlue = True }

List2

{ Id = 1, LikesRed = False, LikesBlue = True }
{ Id = 3, LikesRed = False, LikesBlue = True }
{ Id = 4, LikesRed = True, LikesBlue = False }
```

And here is my intended result:

```
{ Id = 1, LikesRed = True, LikesBlue = True }
{ Id = 2, LikesRed = True, LikesBlue = False }
{ Id = 3, LikesRed = False, LikesBlue = True }
{ Id = 4, LikesRed = True, LikesBlue = True }
```

I've managed to merge both lists (but the items are not grouped) using the following:

```
var results = list1.Concat(list2);
```

I've also attempted to group the items in this list using LINQ (it works, but I'm not sure what I can/should do with it):

```
var final = from x in results
            group x by x.Id into g
            select g;
```

Can anyone offer any advice as to how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check if any items in group has value set to true:

```
from x in list1.Concat(list2)
group x by x.Id into g
select new {
   Id = g.Key,
   LikesRed = g.Any(x => x.LikesRed),
   LikesBlue = g.Any(x => x.LikesBlue)
}
```

Comment: perfect, simple solution!

Answer (score -1):

You can first group the lists by there ids like you already did and dann use [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to overwrite the values with your preferences.